# Cyclical Sliding Window Iteration

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-itertools

Consider some given sequence and a window length, say the `list`

```
a = [13 * i + 1 for i in range(24)]
```

(so that

```
In [61]: a
Out[61]: 
[1,
 14,
 27,
 40,
 ...,
 287,
 300]
```

)

and window length 3.

I'd like to take the sliding window sum of this sequence, but cyclically; i.e., to calculate the length-24 `list`:

```
[sum([1, 14, 27]),
 sum([14, 27, 40]),
 ...,
 sum([287, 300, 1]),
 sum([300, 1, 14])]
```

The best I could come up with, using [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and [Stupid Lambda Tricks](http://p-nand-q.com/python/lambda.html), was

```
d = collections.deque(range(24))
d.rotate(1)
map(lambda _: d.rotate(-1) or sum(a[i] for i in list(d)[: 3]), range(24))
```

Is there something less horrible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about the simple

```
a = [13 * i + 1 for i in range(24)]
w = 3

aa = a + a[:w]
print([sum(aa[i:i+w]) for i in range(len(a))])
```

Note that if the window is big there are better ways to compute a sliding window sum in `O(n)` (i.e. with a constant time per element, independently of the size of the window).

The idea is to do a "scan conversion" replacing each element with the sum of all elements from the start (this requires single pass).

After that the sum of elements from x0 to x1 is then computed in O(1) with

```
sum_table[x1] - sum_table[x0]
```

In code:

```
sum_table = [0]
for v in a:
    sum_table.append(sum_table[-1] + v)
for v in a[:w]:
    sum_table.append(sum_table[-1] + v)
print([sum_table[i+w] - sum_table[i] for i in range(len(a))])
```

Comment: This is better than what I did in every respect. Come to think of the second half of your answer (the classic add-head-subtract-tail), this could be placed in list comprehension as well using the Stupid-Lambda-Trick, no?

Comment: @AmiTavory: I'm used more to building a sum table because often I need to access the sliding window sum randomly and only for a tiny subset of the values. Of course you can also keep a running sum and add/subtract from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind using itertools, this is one solution:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
a_one = islice(cycle(a), 1, None)
a_two = islice(cycle(a), 2, None)
sums = [sum(t) for t in zip(a, a_one, a_two)]
```

You could also write an abstraction for this in terms of the window length:

```
wlen = 3
a_rotations = (islice(cycle(a), i, None) for i in range(1, wlen))
sums = [sum(t) for t in zip(a, *a_rotations)]
```

Here is another solution that is more scalable solution in terms of window length:

```
alen = len(a)
wlen = 3
sums = [sum(a[:wlen])]
for i in range(alen - 1):
    sums.append(sums[i] - a[i] + a[i + wlen - alen])
```

Another solution which efficiently combines the two ideas and borrows the variable save idea from Stefan Pochmann's solution:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
wlen = 3
rotatediterator = islice(cycle(a), wlen, None)
sums = []
lastsum = sum(a[:wlen])
for addval, subval in zip(rotatediterator, a):
    sums.append(lastsum)
    lastsum += addval - subval
```

Comment: Thanks. it would indeed do the job for this case, but I'm not sure it is very scalable (in terms of even writing the code, not the runtime complexity) in the window length. I wrote the same comment to Kasra's answer above.

Comment: @AmiTavory I've updated with a solution that is more scalable in terms of the window length. Using the second solution, both the time complexity, and the code complexity are not affected very much by the size of the window.

Comment: In your last one you could instead add `a[i + wlen - alen]`. I use that in mine as well, negative indexes rule :-)

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any `n` using islice and sum:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def rolling_window(func, l, n):
    for i in xrange(len(l)):
        yield func(islice(cycle(l), i, n+i))


print(list(rolling_window(sum,l,3)))

[42, 81, 120, 159, 198, 237, 276, 315, 354, 393, 432, 471, 510, 549, 588, 627, 666, 705, 744, 783, 822, 861, 588, 315]
```

Or using yield from in python3:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
def rolling_window(func, l, n):
     yield from (func(islice(cycle(l), i, n+i)) for i in range(len(l)))
```

Or using modulo:

```
out, ln, n = [], len(l), 3
sm = sum(l[:n])
for i in range(1, 25):
    out.append(sm)
    sm = sm - l[(i - 1) % ln] + l[(i+n-1) % ln]
print(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

A fast way (at least for large window sizes):

```
sums = []
s = sum(a[:3])
for i, n in enumerate(a, 3-len(a)):
    sums.append(s)
    s += a[i] - n
```

Similar, but using `itertools.accumulate`:

```
acc = list(accumulate([0] + a + a))
print([acc[i+3] - acc[i] for i in range(len(a))])
```

Or like Shashank's but with negative indexes:

```
sums = [sum(a[:3])]
for i in range(-len(a), -1):
    sums.append(sums[-1] - a[i] + a[i+3])
```

And a short and basic one, again using negative indexes:

```
[a[i] + a[i+1] + a[i+2] for i in range(-len(a), 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

At each successive point, add in the new one (`a[i]`) and subtract out the old (`a[i-3]`). To wrap back around, you can chain the ranges.

```
s = [sum(a[:3])]
for i in itertools.chain(range(3,len(a)), range(3)) :
  s.append( s[-1] + a[i] - a[i-3] )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` with `zip` function :

```
>>> new=a+a[:2]
>>> new
[1, 14, 27, 40, 53, 66, 79, 92, 105, 118, 131, 144, 157, 170, 183, 196, 209, 222, 235, 248, 261, 274, 287, 300, 1, 14]
>>> map(sum,zip(new,new[1:],new[2:]))
[42, 81, 120, 159, 198, 237, 276, 315, 354, 393, 432, 471, 510, 549, 588, 627, 666, 705, 744, 783, 822, 861, 588, 315]
>>>
```

Note that we created the `new` with concatenating the first 2 elements of `a` to the end of `a` and `zip(new,new[1:],new[2:])` will give you the desire sub sets then you can use `map` function to apply the `sum` function on it :

```
>>> zip(new,new[1:],new[2:])
[(1, 14, 27), (14, 27, 40), (27, 40, 53), (40, 53, 66), (53, 66, 79), (66, 79, 92), (79, 92, 105), (92, 105, 118), (105, 118, 131), (118, 131, 144), (131, 144, 157), (144, 157, 170), (157, 170, 183), (170, 183, 196), (183, 196, 209), (196, 209, 222), (209, 222, 235), (222, 235, 248), (235, 248, 261), (248, 261, 274), (261, 274, 287), (274, 287, 300), (287, 300, 1), (300, 1, 14)]
```

Comment: That would work. However, suppose the list were of length 10,000, and the sliding window is of length 793. How would it be feasible to write ``zip(new, new[1: ], new[2: ], ... new[792: ])``?

Comment: @AmiTavory `map(sum,zip(*(new[i:] for i in range(3))))`